# Rails paperclip, ImageMagick img upload error - 'no file chosen'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, imagemagick, paperclip, image-upload

Ok, so this is the second time I encounter this problem - see the previous question [Rails paperclip img upload error: "no file chosen" with rmagick installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132916/rails-paperclip-img-upload-error-no-file-chosen-with-rmagick-installed).

Since I didn't come up with u proper solution, I'm not sure what's causing it. From my research it appears that it's because I'm on Windows 7.

I haven't made any changes to the model or form.

But when I try to use the nested form - I simply get **'no file chosen'**

But after creating an Image from console:

```
<te :image => File.open('C:/sites/thrillb/app/assets/images/ins1.jpg')
identify.exe: unable to open image `file': No such file or directory @ error/blo
b.c/OpenBlob/2641.
identify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `file' @ error/constitute
.c/ReadImage/544.
identify.exe: unable to open image `file': No such file or directory @ error/blo
b.c/OpenBlob/2641.
identify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `file' @ error/constitute
.c/ReadImage/544.
identify.exe: unable to open image `file': No such file or directory @ error/blo
b.c/OpenBlob/2641.
identify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `file' @ error/constitute
.c/ReadImage/544.
=> #<Image id: nil, image_file_name: "ins1.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg
", image_file_size: 293718, image_updated_at: "2012-11-03 10:17:11", trip_id: ni
l, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, title: nil, location_id: nil>
irb(main):002:0>
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a similar question was already answered on the imagemagick forum.
see http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20201

please make sure that your apache process runs from your user-id and not as system user; it should fix the issues you reported.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The answer is here - [Paperclip File Not Found Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056932/paperclip-file-not-found-error).

Looks like it was a paperclip error.

Need to add this gem to gemfile:

```
 gem "cocaine", "0.3.2"
```